# Разбить время в миллисекундах на дни/часы/минуты

Tags: время, java

Имеется время

- long lasttime = getLastLogin(user);

Надо **вычесть** из текущего времени (*System.currentTimeMillis()*) время *lasttime* и полученный результат разбить на дни, часы и минуты, чтобы узнать, какое время пользователя нет в сети.

**Обновление**

У меня что-то вроде этого, но я сильно сомневаюсь в точности:

```
long em = (long)((System.currentTimeMillis()-lp) / 1000 / 60L);//min ::
int eh = (int)((em*60)-(int)(em/60));//hour ::
int ed = (int)((em*60*24)-(int)(em/60/24));//day
```

Comment: А как бы вы глядя на секундомер разбили секунды на минуты, часы, дни?

Comment: У меня что-то вроде этого, но я сильно сомневаюсь в точности:
long em = (long)((System.currentTimeMillis()-lp) / 1000 / 60L);//min
int eh = (int)((em*60)-(int)(em/60));//hour
int ed = (int)((em*60*24)-(int)(em/60/24));//day

Answer (score 7):

Можно воспользоваться такими дивными вещами, как Calendar и SimpleDataFormat. Вот пример рабочий:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar dating = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formating = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY:MM:dd:HH:mm:ss:SSS");
        System.out.println( formating.format(dating.getTime()) );

    }
}
```

В результате выполнения мы получим: "2014:07:29:10:22:49:824" (*Результат с теста кода*).

Думаю, код понятен, но стоит сказать по поводу конструктора класса SimpleDataFormat. [Вот здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Описаны все ключи, которые можно использовать в форматировании. Вместо двоеточих можно использовать точки и другие символы. Например:

"YYYY/MM/dd" Выводит: 2014/07/29

"dd MMM YYYY" Выдаст 29 Jul 2014

**На заметку**
SimpleDataFormat хорошо работает и с результатом метода System.currentTimeMillis(), а вот как определять дату, через календарь, или через систему - решать вам.

Стоит отметить, что Calendar имеет такие свойства, как `DAY_OF_WEEK, MONDAY` и т.д. Вот с ними и надо оперировать, что бы узнать разницу между точками отрезка во времени.

---

Конечно, код ниже не является номинантом на "панацею от проблем", но всё же решает данную задачу.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        /* Дата, которую сохранили */
        Calendar SaveData = Calendar.getInstance();

        /* промежуток: тест - 6 секунд */
        Thread.sleep(6000);

        /* текущая дата */
        Calendar CurrentData = Calendar.getInstance();

        /* вычисляем */
        Calendar calculate = Calendar.getInstance();
        calculate.setTime(new Date(CurrentData.getTime().getTime() - SaveData.getTime().getTime()));

        /* Здесь станцуем с бубном, мы получим количество часов, поэтому ручками */
        System.out.println(((calculate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - 1 ) * 24)  + (calculate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) - 11) + ":" + 
                calculate.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + calculate.get(Calendar.SECOND));

    }
}
```

В результате выполнения мы получим 0:0:6 (то есть 6 секунд). Думаю, код понятен. (тестил - работает).

Думаю, что не сложно будет разобраться и с тем, как получить количество дней. Но ещё сделаю заметку. Для идеала надо учитывать и года, так как календарь имеет ограничения по дням, но это не сложно; поэтому, думаю, данную задачу уже решишь ты.